# Building external libraries with cmake

Tags: c++, build, cmake

I'm using cmake to build my library which needs external libraries. Each external library has it's own makefile. When I call this set of commands from my `CMakeLists.txt` file nothing is happening.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

```
add_custom_target(blake
        COMMAND mkdir -p ${LIBSCAPI_BUILDIR}/blake
        && cp -r ${LIBSCAPI_BUILDIR}/lib/BLAKE2/sse/. ${LIBSCAPI_BUILDIR}/BLAKE2
        make -C ${LIBSCAPI_BUILDIR}/BLAKE2
        make -C ${LIBSCAPI_BUILDIR}/BLAKE2 BUILDDIR=$(builddir) install
        cp ${LIBSCAPI_BUILDIR}/BLAKE2/libblake2.a install/lib/
        touch compile-blake)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For build a *target* by default, you need to add *ALL* option to the `add_custom_target` call:

```
add_custom_target(blake ALL
    COMMAND ...
)
```

Comment: When I added 'ALL' option, cmake raise an error : 'mkdir: invalid option -- 'r''

Comment: So, there are problems with your commands. Note, that every new command should be prepended with *COMMAND* keyword: Unlike to `make`, `CMake` doesn't automatically treat newline as new command. `&&` may be replaced with *COMMAND* too: all commands are executed in order, and if any of them fails then building will be terminated. You may find more info in [add_custom_target documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.7/command/add_custom_target.html).